# PHP Comparing a File to a Database

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to upload a file to compare to database, then return a .csv file with all of the lines which do not match. I'm a real newbie at php, so if you could be nice and point me in the right direction, that would be great.

For example:

File uploaded has the following in the first column:
1
2
3
4
5

Database has a table with 1 column:
1
2
3
4
6

File pushed out to the user would have 1 column with:
5

I've used findstr on windows, made a batch script that compares two files.
Also used cat on linux and awk also.
But I'm looking for a more user friendly interface that automates the process.

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately, I cannot find anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I wish SO would allow more than one upvote on the comment.

Answer (score 3):

A lot depends on how the data is held in your script for processing.

If you can get both your database data and your file data into arrays, you can use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the differences between the two on a per-row basis.  Then output the assembled differences using [`fputcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)